# usb_bulk_msg fails on global buffer but works on kmalloc buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, libusb

I was trying to develop a USB device driver under Linux. I have created a simple USB driver to send and receive data over bulk endpoints. Here is the code:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>   // Macros used to mark up functions e.g. __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h> // Core header for loading LKMs into the kernel
#include <linux/device.h> // Header to support the kernel Driver Model
#include <linux/kernel.h> // Contains types, macros, functions for the kernel
#include <linux/fs.h>     // Header for the Linux file system support
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

#define DEVICE_VID 0x0483
#define DEVICE_PID 0xff11

struct usbd_device
{
  struct usb_device *device;
  struct usb_class_driver class;
  struct usb_interface *interface;
  __u8 buffer[64];
  __u8 bulk_in_addr;
  __u8 bulk_out_addr;
};

static struct usbd_device usbd_dev;

static int usbd_open(struct inode *i, struct file *filp)
{
  return 0;
}

static int usbd_close(struct inode *i, struct file *filp)
{
  return 0;
}

static ssize_t usbd_read(struct file *filp, char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
  int ret, cnt;
  memset(usbd_dev.buffer, 0, 64);
  ret = usb_bulk_msg(usbd_dev.device, usb_rcvbulkpipe(usbd_dev.device, usbd_dev.bulk_in_addr), usbd_dev.buffer, 64, &cnt, 1000);

  if (ret) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD BULK READ FAILED!, ERR: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
  }
  if (copy_to_user(buff, usbd_dev.buffer, 2)) {
    return -EFAULT;
  }
  printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD READ %s and %d bytes\n", usbd_dev.buffer, cnt);
  printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD LOL\n");

  return cnt;
}

static ssize_t usbd_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
  int ret, cnt;

  if (copy_from_user(usbd_dev.buffer, buff, 2))
    return -EFAULT;

  ret = usb_bulk_msg(usbd_dev.device, usb_sndbulkpipe(usbd_dev.device, usbd_dev.bulk_out_addr), usbd_dev.buffer, 64, &cnt, 1000);
  if (ret) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD BULK WRITE FAILED!, ERR: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
  }

  printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD WROTE %s and %d bytes\n", usbd_dev.buffer, cnt);
  return cnt;
}

static struct file_operations usbd_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = usbd_open,
    .release = usbd_close,
    .read = usbd_read,
    .write = usbd_write,
};

const struct usb_device_id usbd_table[] = {
    { USB_DEVICE(DEVICE_VID, DEVICE_PID)},
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, usbd_table);

static int usbd_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
  int i, ret;
  struct usb_host_interface *iface_desc;
  struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *ep;

  usbd_dev.device = usb_get_dev(interface_to_usbdev(interface));
  usbd_dev.interface = interface;
  usbd_dev.class.name = "usbd%d";
  usbd_dev.class.fops = &usbd_fops;

  iface_desc = interface->cur_altsetting;

  for (i = 0; i < iface_desc->desc.bNumEndpoints; i++) {
    ep = &iface_desc->endpoint[i].desc;
    if (usb_endpoint_is_bulk_in(ep)) {
      usbd_dev.bulk_in_addr = ep->bEndpointAddress;
      printk(KERN_ALERT "found ep in at %d", usbd_dev.bulk_in_addr);
    }
    if (usb_endpoint_is_bulk_out(ep)) {
      usbd_dev.bulk_out_addr = ep->bEndpointAddress;
      printk(KERN_ALERT "found ep out at %d", usbd_dev.bulk_out_addr);
    }
  }

  if ((ret = usb_register_dev(interface, &usbd_dev.class)) < 0)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD PROBE FAILED!, CANNOT REGISTER DEVICE\n");
  else
    printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD PROBE SUCCESS! minor: %d\n", interface->minor);

  return ret;
}

static void usbd_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
  usb_deregister_dev(interface, &usbd_dev.class);
  printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD DISCONNECT SUCCESS!\n");
}

static struct usb_driver usbd = {
    .name = "usbd",
    .probe = usbd_probe,
    .disconnect = usbd_disconnect,
    .id_table = usbd_table,
};

static int __init usbd_init(void)
{
  int result;

  result = usb_register(&usbd);
  if (result < 0) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "error registering : usbd");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

static void __exit usbd_exit(void)
{
  usb_deregister(&usbd);
}

module_init(usbd_init);
module_exit(usbd_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Ankit Sharma");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple linux usb driver");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
```

The problem is that I cannot send to or receive from the USB device any data. `usb_bulk_msg()` returns successfully but there is no data in `usbd_dev.buffer` although `cnt` (bytes read variable) shows that 64 bytes were read. When I switch from a static global buffer (`usbd_dev.buffer`) to a local buffer allocated dynamically via `kmalloc()` like this:

```c
  int ret, cnt = 0;
  uint8_t *b;
  b = kzalloc(64,GFP_KERNEL);

  ret = usb_bulk_msg(usbd_dev.device, usb_rcvbulkpipe(usbd_dev.device, usbd_dev.bulk_in_addr), b, 64, &cnt, 1000);
  if (ret) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD BULK READ FAILED!, ERR: %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
  }
  if (copy_to_user(buff, b, min(len,64)))
    return -EFAULT;
  printk(KERN_ALERT "USBD READ %s and %d bytes\n", b, cnt);
  kfree(b);
```

everything works fine. Why is this happening? Why cant I read into a static buffer initialised inside the structure? why do I need to allocate memory dynamically from the heap via `kmalloc()`?

Comment: It is an agreement that all buffers for the USB messages **must** be allocated on the heap. Technical background: DMA.

Comment: can you please post any links or discussions or any where on the web where i can read more about this? and what other parts of the kernel sub system require dynamic memory allocations?

Comment: and how does the called function know that the pointer to the buffer passed is something allocated statically or taken from the kernels heap?

Comment: As I wrote above, read about DMA and how it works in hardware and in Linux in particular.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/message.c#L335, https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch13.html.

Comment: i found more documentaion related to this here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt for anyone who faces this issue.